# arranging input data in POST-array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, forms

I created a form that consists of an amount of similar areas. Those areas can be added using jQuery. Each area equals one workstep used to asemble a product and therefore it has the same input-fields (description, duration,...). Here is the code (it is simplified to two hard-coded areas):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="insertNewProduct.php" method="post">
    <fieldset id="product-fieldset">
        <legend>Produkt</legend>
        <div id="step-container">
            <input type="hidden" name="step[]" />
            <div id="step-table" class="product-table">
                <table id="basis-table">
                    <!-- STEP-BASISDATEN -->
                    <thead id="step-basis">
                        <!-- Basisdaten Schritt -->
                        <tr>
                            <th class="data-title">Arbeitsschritt</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Bezeichnung:</th>
                            <td><input type="text" name="step[0][stepDescr]"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Dauer:</th>
                            <td><input type="text" name="step[0][stepDur]"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>

            <div id="step-table" class="product-table">
                <table id="basis-table">
                    <!-- STEP-BASISDATEN -->
                    <thead id="step-basis">
                        <!-- Basisdaten Schritt -->

                        <tr>
                            <th class="data-title">Arbeitsschritt</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Bezeichnung:</th>
                            <td><input type="text" name="step[1][stepDescr]"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Dauer:</th>
                            <td><input type="text" name="step[1][stepDur]"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" id="sendForm" value="Send"><input type="reset" id="resetForm" value="Reset">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I added numbers to the steps

```
name="step[0][stepDescr]"
```

and therefore I get the desired result:

```
Array
(
    [step] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [stepDescr] => 
                    [stepDur] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [stepDescr] => 
                    [stepDur] => 
                )

        )

)
```

If I don't use the numbers my array becomes of course unusable:

```
Array
(
    [step] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [stepDescr] => 
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [stepDur] => 
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [stepDescr] => 
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [stepDur] => 
                )

        )

)
```

How can I add these numbers (based on the amount of steps) to my HTML-Code (!) using jQuery?

Comment: You can use `for()` or `foreach()` loop in php and print this.

Comment: I don't want to re-arange and process the array using php. It's my aim to submit a fitting array. I think - if you have like 100 worksteps or even more - it becomes very complicated to change the array-order correctly once submitted.

Comment: Check my answer. maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [custom attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#custom-data-attribute). They are part of the HTML5 spec.

> Custom data attributes are intended to store custom data private to the page or application, for which there are no more appropriate attributes or elements.

The name for the input fields could be stored in a custom attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="step[0][stepDescr]" data-name="stepDescr" />
```

And in your function to clone your fieldset construct the name based on the count of your step container. Be sure to change the ids of the elements to classes, as they aren't unique anymore if you clone them.

```
function addStep(){
    var count = $('.step-container').length;
    var $container = $('.step-container:last').clone();
    $container.find(':input').each(function(){
        var input_name = 'step['+count+']['+$(this).attr("data-name")+']';
        $(this).attr('name', input_name);
    });
    $container.appendTo("#product-fieldset");
};
```

Comment: thank you, that helped a lot. Can you give me some additional information about this "data-name"-thing?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this should do the trick.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var areaNbr = 0;
    function addArea(frm) {
        areaNbr ++;
        var area = '<p id="area'+areaNbr+'">Bezeichnung: <input type="text" name="step['+areaNbr+'][stepDescr]"> Dauer: <input type="text" name="step['+areaNbr+'][stepDur]"> <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeArea('+areaNbr+');">';
        jQuery('#step-container').append(area);
    }

    function removeArea(areaNum) {
        jQuery('#area'+areaNum).remove();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="insertNewProduct.php" method="post">
    <fieldset id="product-fieldset">
        <legend>Produkt</legend>
        <div id="step-container">
            <input type="hidden" name="step[]" />
            <p id="area0">Bezeichnung: <input type="text" name="step[0][stepDescr]"> Dauer: <input type="text" name="step[0][stepDur]"> <input onclick="addArea(this.form);" type="button" value="Add Area" /> </p>
            </div>


        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" id="sendForm" value="Send"><input type="reset" id="resetForm" value="Reset">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Indeed also a helpful answer! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to use loop using php :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="insertNewProduct.php" method="post">
    <fieldset id="product-fieldset">
        <legend>Produkt</legend>
        <div id="step-container">
            <input type="hidden" name="step[]" />
            <?php for($i=0;$i<2;$i++) { ?>
            <div id="step-table" class="product-table">
                <table id="basis-table">
                    <!-- STEP-BASISDATEN -->
                    <thead id="step-basis">
                        <!-- Basisdaten Schritt -->
                        <tr>
                            <th class="data-title">Arbeitsschritt</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Bezeichnung:</th>
                            <td><input type="text" name="step[<?php echo $i; ?>][stepDescr]"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Dauer:</th>
                            <td><input type="text" name="step[<?php echo $i; ?>][stepDur]"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>                
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" id="sendForm" value="Send"><input type="reset" id="resetForm" value="Reset">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You had the same idea like the person above. Therefore my answer is the same.